# How to do batch processing to find and blur texts in images?

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition

Is there a tool which can be used to automatically find and blur all texts in a set of photos?

The texts can appear in all formats one can imagine, from documents lying on a table to a screen showing a document to (house)number plates, bottles, calendars and others.

The reason for why i want to blur the texts is that they might contain hints to personal data.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing end-user solution or to develop a custom app?  Either way, you'll need some type of OCR or computer vision to determine where the text information is to blur.

Comment: @BenThompson it would be great if an existing app could do this; even a (moderately) paid one, but so far i couldn't find anything close.

The problem with ocr is that, i think, it normally isn't meant to detect transformed text in a natural scene. I'm already playing around with openCV and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03155) but haven't got anything useful yet.
I'm fine with a custom app in whatever language but it shouldn't be too involved but be possible to use high level apis.